# Ruby CSV Capybara

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm writing an automated test at a request from a lead developer.

Part of the webpage being developed is to allow a user to extract a csv of data.  In the past there have been many defects around ordering of the headers within the csv.

I need to open the csv, convert the headers into an array and compare against an array I've created of expected headers.

I've read the documentation for CSV in Ruby 2.0 but I'm pretty new to Ruby and I'm struggling to make sense of it all.

So expect the first header in the csv to eql the first header in my own array.

How would I successfully convert the csv file headers to an array and compare to the other array please?

Answer (score 0):

`CSV.parse` does what you want, as long as you tell it you have headers in the file.

```
c = CSV.parse("a,b,c\n1,2,3", headers: true)
c.headers  # => ["a", "b", "c"]
```

You can then compare that in your tests.